# Integrals Regulated functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, integration

stuck on an example for this question,

Give an example of a regulated function $f \colon [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ with the properties that $\forall x \in [a,b] f(x) \ge 0 , \int_a^b f = 0$ and there is $c \in [a,b]$ with $f(c) > 0$

I think a function that fits though would be one where $f(0) = y_0$ where $y_0 > 0$, and f is 0 everywhere else, but im not sure how to show that this is regulated? Im not even sure if it is?

A function is $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is a regulated function if given $\epsilon>0$ there is a step function $\phi\colon[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ s.t $||f-\phi||_\infty < \epsilon$ (equivalently $|f(x) - \phi(x) | < \epsilon \forall x \in [a,b]$) .

Comment: What does "regulated" mean, in this context?

Comment: Also, is it known that $a\leq 0\leq b$?

Comment: check edit for definition. Also it is not know that $a\le0\le b $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that $f\colon [a,b]\to\mathbb R$ is defined as regulated iff $\lim_{t\to x^-}f(t)$ exists for all $x\in(a,b]$ and $\lim_{t\to x^+}f(t)$ exists for all $x\in [a,b)$.

In that case, for example
$$ f(x)=\begin{cases}y_0&\text{if }x=a,\\y_1&\text{if }x=b,\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
is a regulated function (all limits to be considered are $0$. If you pick $y_0>0$ and/or $y_1>0$, you get an exapmple as required (indeed, the integral $\int_a^bf\,\mathrm dx$ does not depend on values at single points)

---

*Edit:* The definition I used above is known to be equivalent to what you added to the question (cf. Dieudonné, Jean (1969), *Foundations of Modern Analysis*). But in fact $f$ itself is a step function, that is the linear combination of indicator functions of intervals. It is just that we need to recognize single points as special cases of intervals:
$$f= y_0\cdot 1_{[a,a]}+y_1\cdot 1_{[b,b]}.$$